# how to intercept HTML response with Ajax cross-domain call with jquery lib

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I've a login form that call an external controller page that returns an HTML page with TRUE or FALSE message. I've wrote this jQuery function:

```
$("#login").click(function(){
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: $('#form_login').serialize(),
  jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
  url: "http://news.univadis.it/autenticazione/autentication.asp",
  complete: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        $("#output").html(data);
   }
});
});
```

but when I try to stamp the message "TRUE" or "FALSE" Firebug return this error:

```
XML tag name mismatch (expected meta) </head>
```

this is cause the response is in HTML and not in Json, how can I intercept the HTML response?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work.

JSONP is actually a hack, when you request a cross-domain resource with JSONP request the jQuery library inserts a `<script/>` node to head of the HTML document with the URL you've provided.

So from your AJAX request the following script node will be created:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://news.univadis.it/autenticazione/autentication.asp?jsonp_callback=jQuery17108946618142072111_1326271422070&_=1326271651101"/>
```

Of course the actual parameters will be differ, but it will look like this. The webserver should send a prepared JavaScript response. Prepared response means that the actual response should been wrapped with a JavaScript function call, in this example:

```
jQuery17108946618142072111_1326271422070('this is your data');
```

Without that the callback you'll never get your response.

That's why you cannot "intercept" HTML response with JSONP requests.

Comment: I'm sorry, how can i modify correctly the 'success' status callback to manage the response?